Doesn't our awareness of qualia imply the brain is non-deterministic?
Even if we had a full description of how the brain physically works to transform inputs into outputs, this would not be satisfying enough and we would claim it doesn't explain why there's qualia associated to all this computation.
In fact, if this description was deterministic, we could simulate a brain and ask it "is this a complete description of how you work?" If it claimed not to be, that would be illogical as its output depends only on the math, and it would be a mistake for it to not accept the possibility that that's all there is. Even if somehow running the simulation produced qualia, the qualia would have no effect on the output, so it would be unaware of it.
The conclusion then is that humans cannot be fully deterministic since it would be illogical for us to know about the existence of this extra thing called "qualia".
Isn't this a simple and obvious proof that the brain cannot be explained by purely deterministic physics?

+1 Science would rather have religion with belief in the after-world to discuss "qualia"

In philosophy of mind your question is similar to the famous thought experiment of Chalmers' p-zombies' possibility which was established to logically refute materialism or accept panpsychic neutral monism. Therefore if a brain can be successfully deterministically simulated implying the existence of deterministic p-zombies, it implies materialistic and physicalistic monism of mind are absolutely impossible. OTOH if neither deterministic nor non-deterministic p-zombies is slightly possible, then based on your premise of the existence of qualia, dual-property neutral monism is necessary...

@Stefan For me it is totally unclear what you mean by "ask it", i.e. by asking the brain simulation. Please elaborate you idea. Currently, your thought experiment is floating in the air. One cannot draw any conclusion from it. - Possibly it helps to argue on the basis of current neuroscience. See the search for the neural correlates of consicousness (NCC) en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_correlates_of_consciousness

Voting to close because the question misunderstands basic terminology and concepts, and so answers would have to clear that up first before answering.

Of course all the brain functions cannot be explained by deterministic physics. The cognitive functions cannot be explained or even described by any kind of physics. Psychology is a completely different  branch of science.

Stefan, you are asking one of the most compelling and challenging questions of this time or all time.  It would be like coming on here and asking "I've been wondering if God exists or not, what is the answer?" or "What is dark matter?" or "How do quantum physics and general relativity fit together?" or "How did the universe begin?"  Nobody has the slightest clue - maybe in 10 or 20 thousand years there will be an answer!

Stefan I direct you to https://www.youtube.com/@CloserToTruthTV with Robert Khun. It has literally 100s of interviews with, literally, every single living figure in philosophy and science, discussing exactly this issue, heh!  (The outcome is "nobody has a clue" but it's amaazing to hear the variety of opinions.)

Stefan if you're looking in to this sort of thing, "emergence" (sorry, "Emergence!") is the latest blah blah in mankind's search for the understanding of how free will exists.  Read up on it, or better, just go here and enjoy all the videos with "emergene" or "free will" in the title. https://www.youtube.com/@CloserToTruthTV/videos?view=0&sort=dd&shelf_id=5  Again, incredibly, literally every living philosopher or scientist who works with the questions you ask about are represented on there!  it's quite amazing!  Just one example, the most recent (of the many) talks by Dennett in there deals

.. with precisely your question - !

I agree with @MisterMiyagi in that your thought experiment with the simulated brain doesn't seem to be logically consistent. If my own, real brain cannot answer the presented question ("Is this how you work?") then why should a simulated brain fair any better?
For what it's worth, you're asking a good question. Part of the problem is understanding where qualia are "staged". We understand if we see a ball, a real ball likely exists in space and time. But if we imagine a ball, where is that ball? Where does the action of qualia take place? I agree that "the brain" is an unsatisfying answer.

"if this description was deterministic, we could simulate a brain and ask it...its output depends only on the math" - We can't currently simulate a brain specifically because we don't know all the math yet, so we don't know what such a simulation would tell us. You're assuming here that the math/complete description wouldn't imply qualia (however you wish to define that). It's also somewhat unclear what the relation between qualia (subjective experiences) and determinism is meant to be here.

"is this a complete description of how you work?" why do you expect a simulated brain to be able to answer this, if a real brain couldn't answer this either?

Here's a picture of how it works according to the opposing side. You may not agree with this picture, but it should answer your question, by showing you a point of view where the contradictions you raised disappear.
According to this picture, the brain is mechanistic, obeying the mathematical laws of physics. The brain emits "C-statements"; these are defined as statements like "I am conscious," or "I can see a ball of string." The brain evolved to make such statements because it is useful for the organism to be able to reason about what information it does or does not have access to. For example, if you're hunting a rabbit and saw it recently but can't see it now, it is useful to be able to verbalize such thoughts, so that you can think about where it might have gone. From the mechanistic perspective, C-statements are really statements about what information is accessible to the decision-making systems of the brain.
Simultaneously, from the conscious perspective, the conscious mind also has qualia, and can think about these qualia. From the conscious perspective, C-statements are interpreted as statements about what is subjectively perceived.
So there are two perspectives, the conscious perspective and the mechanistic perspective. Each perspective has an interpretation of C-statements. But these two interpretations correspond to each other; whenever you subjectively perceive something from the conscious perspective, your brain has access to corresponding information from the mechanistic perspective. So there is no contradiction. If you ask someone what they can see, on one level they are reporting the contents of their consciousness, and on another level they are reporting what visual information is accessible to their decision-making faculties, and these two levels are fundamentally equivalent and about the same thing.

C-statements, I would say, correspond to verbal, necessarily partial descriptions of thoughts (states and processes in the brain, including perceptions) - so why assume there are separate "qualia" or why assume there are two levels? Why not just say that "I feel sad/glad" or "The subject feels sad/glad" summarize in a rather crude way some current complex neurological state, rather than speak of two levels?

Or is that what you are saying? Both ways of speaking about conscious processes (the psychological talk or the introspective talk on the one hand and the neurological process talk on the other hand) refer to one and the same process, and are in that regard equivalent?

@mudskipper Yes, they are equivalent. They are two perspectives on the same thing. It's like two people looking at the same cow from different sides. They may describe different observations, but it's the same cow.

Ok, got it - thanks - then I totally agree with this.

Qualia are consistent with both deterministic and non-deterministic theories.
Now to your specific propositions...

if this description was deterministic, we could simulate a brain

This is not necessarily true.

Even if somehow running the simulation produced qualia, the qualia would have no effect on the output, so it would be unaware of it

Qualia not affecting the output does not imply non-awareness. Further, the assertion that simulation-produced qualia has no effect on the output is not necessarily true. Our many experiences of qualia arguably affect our "output." E.g. we talk about them.

The conclusion then is that humans cannot be fully deterministic since it would be illogical for us to know about the existence of this extra thing called "qualia".

That doesn't follow from any of the propositions you assert earlier in the question, even if one takes them as true. You also haven't established why it would make sense to call qualia some "extra thing" that needs special treatment in this thought experiment or argument.

Isn't this a simple and obvious proof that the brain cannot be explained by purely deterministic physics?

Negative.

"This is not necessarily true." By a complete description I mean a set of equations, or a computer program, that we can put numbers into (representing brain inputs from our sensory organs) and get numbers out of (representing the brain's outputs to muscles). If it is deterministic (each input determines a unique output), what stops us from running all the math and predicting exactly how we would act for a given question?

I'm not sure why you're saying we couldn't simulate a complete, deterministic, model of the brain then.

You said "This is not necessarily true." in response to my statement that we could not run a fully deterministic model of the brain. I'm confused why you're saying that when to me that's the definition of deterministic - a model that we could put in inputs and compute a unique output, and always matches the result of doing the same experiment in reality.

I'm not sure what other definitions there are, but this is the only one I know: "A deterministic model will thus always produce the same output from a given starting condition or initial state.". A deterministic brain model would let us compute a unique response for each input to the brain. A non-deterministic brain model would not be able to predict a unique response (maybe it would predict a set of possible responses).

You can think of a model as a function taking in the current state of the system and returning the set of possible future states. To be deterministic means that each current state can evolve to a single future state. This agrees with every definition I've seen, whether in computer science (for example, deterministic turing machines), or in physics (for example, classical physics is deterministics as it allows us to predict the future state of the system given the current state with 100% certainty, vs in quantum physics where we can only predict a probability distribution).

If you're using a different definition, you're using the non-standard one.

For your second point, what I meant was that it's possible in a weird way that running a simulation of a model produces qualia, despite the model output not depending in any way on it, but that would be irrelevant as the model would act just the same without it. I've reworded the question to "our awareness of qualia" instead of "the existence of qualia".

As for the third point, this is my assumption, that a person given a complete description of the brain's physics would be unsatisfied and ask "I see how inputs lead to outputs, why should any of this explain qualia?" which is why I call qualia this "extra thing" that can't be covered by any physical description.

I agree that we might not be able to physically simulate the model on a computer, I meant it more as a thought experiment that in theory the model could be run (assuming an infinitely powerful computer existed). The point was that if the simulated brain is logical, it should not claim that its behavior is influenced by anything outside the model (because it isn't, there's no outside input to the model), and claiming there is more left to be explained (for example, qualia) would be such a statement.

@Stefan Recall the Busy Beaver score functions from mathematics/computer science. They are a classic family of examples of uncomputable functions. These functions are well-defined. Every input has a single valid output. But, there is no algorithm that could possibly tell us what these inputs are. Even though the outputs are completely determined by the inputs, and no external factors influence the result, there is no way a computer, regardless of power, can take us from input to output.

@Stefan Simulating a brain might be a task too complex in practice at any level of technological development. Though of course instead of simulation you could instead talk about an exact copy of a brain. But that's not enough, you'd need to create the same environment to get the same outcome.

@Stefan I don't see why the inability to go from "here's the physics of the brain" to "here's qualia" should be seen as anything other than a human limitation. We can't expect to "see" the high level (potential) consequences from a very low level description, without some intervening help. But that's a statement about humans and not about "the world". Conway's game of life can be described in a sentence, but that doesn't let me see how you can make self replicating Turing complete patterns. I don't see automobiles anywhere in quantum field theory, but cars are surely physically explainable.

Your argument seems like circular reasoning to me.

Even if we had a full description of how the brain physically
works...this would not be satisfying enough and we would claim it
doesn't explain why there's qualia....

Why?  Why wouldn't a "full description" explain qualia?  Another view might be that it wouldn't be a full, physical description unless it explained qualia. The opening statement seems to rely on the assumption that qualia are not physically explainable; i.e, that they are not deterministic. The argument is opening with its own conclusion as a premise.

Even if somehow running the simulation produced qualia, the qualia
would have no effect on the output, so it would be unaware of it.

Again, why?  How do you know qualia would have no effect on the output?  Humans talk about our own qualia.  We even have arguments:

Is the red I see the same red that you see?

If a tree falls in a forest, and there is no one around to hear it, is there any sound?


Isn't that an "effect" on the output?  Even if the qualia had no effect on the output, how does that prove the simulation is unaware of them?  That statement, particularly that the simulation is unaware of its own qaulia, again seems to assume the conclusion: The simulation is purely physical, qualia are not, therefore the simulation isn't aware of them.
Ultimately, this feels akin to a "god of the gaps" argument: "We don't understand how qualia are produced. Therefore the explanation must be the one I prefer."

"Is the red I see the same red that you see?" Answer: yes. This one proved suitable for scientific attack by reproducible experiment. Unfortunately it taught us nothing about the mind; but rather a little bit about the brain vision circuits.

Minds being deterministic does not imply or require physicalism. Take your fanciest deeply religious or new age dualism belief, that your mind is millions of years old, traveled throughout many dimensions in many shapes, becomes a unicorn after your death and then rides along other souls on the eternal hunting grounds of Valhalla. Whatever. All that can still mean that the mind is fully deterministic all that time, and also predetermined and fully predictable and there is no free will for that mind.
Determinism is possible with many non-physicalist positions, So  whatever view you may choose to "explain" qualia, it won't necessarily disqualify determinism.
Maybe it means minds cannot be simulated on computers and are not explainable by physicalism, but that does not mean non-determinism.
Conversely, something being deterministic also does not strictly imply computability. The Halteproblem is an obvious example, but there are also other ways such as minds being controlled like puppets by gods.

Even if somehow running the simulation produced qualia, the qualia would have no effect on the output, so it would be unaware of it.

Take any known optical illusion. There are color illusions, you can search the internet for "red cola can illusion" for one. If we can ask an AI to describe such images and it reports there is a red can, even though there are no red pixels, then this is (with some fingerprint) an indication of that AI having qualia. This means perceptional phenomena which do change the output of computation.
Note I am not aware of any study of AI having done such a thing yet, but with everything else we see lately, it would not surprise much to get such news soon.
(The fineprint is that AIs can likely be trained to some degree to recognize some illusions, and thus giving a correct response for a known example would not yet be useful proof.)

Apparently there are already systems that are fooled by the same optical illusions that can fool us:
(1) https://www.brown.edu/news/2018-09-21/illusions
(2) https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/optical-illusions-can-fool-ai-chatbots-too/ (behind paywall, so I couldn't read it)
I believe MIT and Stanford have also done research on this - Couldn't quickly find references though. (But the usual visual recognition systems are fooled by their own kind of optical illusions - imperceptible to us. This is well-known. So why not count those in here?)

I was not aware of those, and I feel that's a bit too bleeding edge yet to count as proof, but thanks for the reference.

Some of those systems have been trained by humans, i.e. in the same way we teach a child that a can of Cola is "red" — whatever the child's (or ours!) internal representation is — we also tell AIs that we see a red can of Cola, and they learn to "see" Cola as being "red", even if the pixels are of a completely different colour. You can even ask the AI: "What do you see?" "A can of Cola" "In this picture, what colour is the can?" "Red." This is commonly known as a built-in bias, but, otherwise, what would be the point, if AIs didn't tell us what a human would think? :-)

@GwynethLlewelyn, the point is, that if you merely train the ai to say red for stripes of cyan, it may also say red for just a cyan area. So the question here was whether models can be trained to see illusionary colors only in specific situations, but not in others. Only when such models then see other illusions in which they were not trained would a result become relevant.

@tkruse had I commented on this point five years ago, I would totally agree with you. These days, however, I take nothing for granted from the AI crowd. What these generative models can produce nowadays is mind-boggling (to the AI researchers as well) — they can certainly apply knowledge from one area to a completely different one and still respond like a human would.

And AIs are being constantly trained (by humans) to deal with increasingly complex edge cases — so, in my example above, if I'd lifted a bottle of beer and asked the AI "What colour is this can of Cola?" the AI would answer "That's not a can of Cola, it's a bottle of beer. Cans of Cola are usually red." — even without the picture having any can of Cola visible at all. Current-generation generative AIs is as close as we get to p-zombies — they behave as if they were human, in surprising ways, even if we know that they aren't. But they are very good pretenders!

@GwynethLlewelyn, I don't care how much your mind is boggled, and I am not interested is some contest of who can best guess the future of genAI. I am making a philosophical point here about a boundary for ai to be subject to illusions due to qualia or not. And positive examples of ai responding as if it saw the illusion of course need to be treated with caution. But the question remains whether there are illusions that cannot be trained to generalize without overgeneralized regardless of how much training is given.

It is conceivable that of all illusion human perception suffers, some can be trained to models, yet some others cannot. Once that is known, definition of qualia may change.

Suppose a person has a disease in his eyes, but his brain is intact. Then we can say that the person received the wrong external information, resulting in his final understanding of the world is biased. If the opposite is the case, we can say that the person is receiving the correct information, but the brain cannot synthesize this information, so we cannot say that he has a distorted understanding of the world, but rather that he is unable to understand the world.
Because information from the outside world comes to our brains as a bunch of representations, cognition is essentially the ability to synthesize these representations into ordered knowledge. Only knowledge can be expressed in terms of certainty.
As we all know, human sensory capacity is very limited, and we can never receive complete information about the object itself in the objective world. So even though our brain is an incredible supercomputer, we can't be sure what the outside world is really like, because the information is always incomplete.
So, we can't say that the brain is indeterminate, it's just a computing unit. Incompleteness and inaccuracy of input information will inevitably lead to incompleteness and inaccuracy of output results.
Knowledge also shows that the brain is a powerful tool for certainty, such as the existence of gravity by observing the fall of an apple.

Capsule overview answer:

Isn't this a simple and obvious proof that the brain cannot be explained by purely deterministic physics?

The argument or thought experiment you have stumbled on is very well known for 200 ? plus years and is one of many well-known such thought experiments endlessly debated.
(Obviously no "answer or resolution" has been found: at this stage we know utterly nothing, at all, about as simple a physical gross property as say "gas pressure", far less "free will & consciousness".)
